# how to check a Dictionary key particular row value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Here is my Dictionary:

```
dict = {'UID1':     USER ID       Table    EMAIL
                    user1         tbl1     abc
                    user1         tbl2     abc
                    user1         tbl3     abc
        'UID2':    USER ID       Table     EMAIL
                    user2         tbl4     efg
                    user2         tbl5     efg
                    user2         tbl6     efg}
```

I would like to iterate over dictionary and fetch Email column first value as abc

```
for key in dict:
mgr = dict[key]['EMAIL'][1]
print(mgr)
```

This code gives error: pls help to fetch the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas count from `0`, so for first value by position use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) with `0`:

```
for key, val in dict.items():
    mgr = val['EMAIL'].iat[0]
    print(mgr)
```

Or is possible use [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) with position of column `EMAIL` by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
for key, val in dict.items():
    mgr = val.iat[0, val.columns.get_loc('EMAIL')]
    print(mgr)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. How can I get the column values without indexes from the dictionary.     val['EMAIL'] gives column values with indexes.

Comment: @Rashmi - Use `L = val['EMAIL'].tolist()`